# REST API designing for resource with aggregated property

Tags: rest, aggregate, api-design, endpoint

We are currently trying to come up with a set of REST API that would fit our resource models.

A simplified example of the resource is:

```
CompanyInfo: {
   totalNumberOfEmployees: Number,
   employees: [...employees],
}

Employee: {
   name: String,
}
```

In this case, "CompanyInfo" is like a virtual resource that does not exist in DB. It is a short cut for getting all the data related to the Company resource. The idea was to reduce the amount of logic on FE and create more convenient endpoint instead.

Our current endpoint design is:

```
   GET /api/companyInfos/{companyId}/employees

   GET,POST,PUT,DELETE /api/companyInfos/{companyId}/employees/{employeeId}
```

The reason for the extra {companyId} is because these endpoint does not return "Employees", it instead return a "CompanyInfo" that contains "Employees" embedded in the payload.

This is to avoid the aggregated property "totalNumberOfEmployees" not being updated in case sync when we call POST to create a new "Employee"

So my questions are:

- Is this the correct approach to the problem of "too many requests" or "too much logic in FE"?
- Is it acceptable for the endpoint to return a completely different resource than what its url describe?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

For your Fist question

Is this the correct approach to the problem of "too many requests" or "too much logic in FE"?

yes Sometimes this is how it is suppose to be done. when data sent  is small  in each request. to many request does not affect the performance so This is how it is suppose to be done .

And Generally it is recommended to write one monolithic Ajax call in front end which will be capable of making any kind of call , By taking callback as parameter, and method , arguments as parameters .

So it will not be to much of logic if you follow this approach . All you have to write is callback for each of Ajax call . How ever sometimes situation may not allow for this Example:if you are using content-type like 'multipart/mixed'
there you have to write another ajax call code

However nowdays most front end has too much of logic based on how interactive website is . So your primary concern should be about look of web site .

For you second question

Is it acceptable for the endpoint to return a completely different resource than what its url describe?

yes . It is acceptable . but it is recommended that client mention all the MIME types which it expects in Accept header and Only those MIME types should be returned by Api.